# Populate a new array by looping through another array

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, calculation

I am working on some calculations. By user input, calculations should take place and build a table with data.
My first array, `calcTable` is working as intended, each row however, represents a month. In my final table, I want a row to represent a year.

So I am currently trying to populate a new array, `calcTableShow` that will hold this data. I am having problems with the logic inside the loop that populates `calcTableShow`. The logic can be seen in this image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zi5VR.png
The colors are showing my desired logic between the two tables (arrays).

Another way of calculating the payment and the interest columns in the `calcTableShow` array, could be: 
*Example with payment:*
CalcTableShow.payment(p1) = CalcTable.totPayment(p12)-CalcTable.totPayment(p0)
CalcTableShow.payment(p2) = CalcTable.totPayment(p24)-CalcTable.totPayment(p12)
more...iterations
Same logic with the interest column.

Please take a look at my code. The new code with yearly periods can be found at the bottom of the javascript code, it is currently in a comment.

My main problem currently is how to populate the new array in the correct way.
Also, while typing here at SO, I was thinking that maybe there is a **solution with only one loop**, that will only create one array (/table)? Would that be a better option perhaps?

I hope this makes sense, thanks in advance,
--Frank

```js
calculate();

//*********************************************
//************ LINK the INPUTS ****************
//*********************************************

// Select all inputs and add event listener "change" (for calc only).
var inputsArray = document.querySelectorAll("input");
inputsArray.forEach(el => el.addEventListener("change", calculate));

//inputsArray.forEach(el => el.addEventListener("input", linkValue));
//"input"... will cause massive lag with high "t" values...

// Select all inputs and add event listener "input" (for linking values only)
var inputsArrayTwo = document.querySelectorAll("input");
inputsArray.forEach(el => el.addEventListener("input", linkValue));

// Link the range with number inputs
function linkValue(e) {
  var sibling = e.target.previousElementSibling || e.target.nextElementSibling;
  sibling.value = e.target.value;
}

//*********************************************
//************ UPDATE TABLE OBJECT ************
//*********************************************
function calculate() {
  //*********************************************
  //************ VARS and CALCS *****************
  //*********************************************

  let P = parseFloat(document.querySelector("#calc_P").value);//principal
  let r = document.querySelector("#calc_r").value / 100;//interest
  let n = 12;//compounds
  let t = parseFloat(document.querySelector("#calc_t").value);//time in years
  let A = parseFloat(document.querySelector("#calc_A").value);//deposits
  let p = 12;//periods per year (months)

  let nper = p * t;//total number of periods
  let rate = (1 + r / n) ** (n / p) - 1;// calculation rate
  let F = P * (1 + rate) ** nper + (A * ((1 + rate) ** nper - 1)) / rate;//final value

  //test-array
  let calcTable = [];

  calcTable.push({
    period: 0,
    payment: 0,
    totPayment: P,
    interest: 0,
    totInterest: 0,
    balance: P
  });

  for (let i = 1; i < nper + 1; i++) {
    let previous = i - 1;
    let interest = calcTable[previous].balance * rate;
    calcTable[i] = {
      period: i,
      payment: A,
      totPayment: (P += A),
      interest,
      totInterest: interest + calcTable[previous].totInterest,
      balance: calcTable[previous].balance + A + interest
    };
  }
  /* THESE FUNCTIONS SHOULD LATER APPLY TO THE NEW ARRAY WITH YEARLY PERIODS
  function setPrecision(table) {
    for (let i = 0; i < table.length; i++) {
      for (let key in table[i]) {
        if (key === "interest" || key === "totInterest" || key === "balance") {
          table[i][key] = table[i][key].toFixed(0);
        }
      }
    }
  }

  setPrecision(calcTable);

  function localeSet(table) {
    for (let i = 0; i < table.length; i++) {
      for (let key in table[i]) {
        if (key === "interest" || key === "totInterest" || key === "balance") {
          table[i][key] = new Intl.NumberFormat("fr", {
            minimumFractionDigits: 0
          }).format(table[i][key]);
        } else {
          table[i][key] = new Intl.NumberFormat("fr").format(table[i][key]);
        }
      }
    }
  }
  localeSet(calcTable);
  */

  //*********************************************
  //************* CREATE HTML TABLE *************
  //*********************************************

  var tableSelector = "TblCalc";

  //call the jsonToTable Function
  jsonToTable(calcTable, tableSelector);

  function addEl(parent, nodeName, className) {
    var element = document.createElement(nodeName);
    if (className) element.className = className;
    if (parent) parent.appendChild(element);
    return element;
  }
  function addText(parent, text) {
    parent.appendChild(document.createTextNode(text));
  }
  function jsonToTable(json, selector) {
    var table = addEl(null, "table", "tbl-container");
    var tbody = addEl(table, "tbody");
    var thr = addEl(tbody, "tr", "tbl-headers");

    //loop through the property names of the first object
    for (var propertyName in json[0]) {
      addText(addEl(thr, "th"), propertyName);
    }

    //loop through the array of objects
    for (var ind = 0; ind < json.length; ind++) {
      var item = json[ind];
      var tr = addEl(tbody, "tr", "tbl-rows");
      //loop though each of the objects properties
      var first = ind != json.length - 1; // no first item for last row
      for (var key in item) {
        var el = addEl(tr, "td");
        if (first) {
          // <---- point of interest
          el = addEl(el, "div", "tbl-name-container ");
          el = addEl(el, "div", "tbl-name-text");
          first = false;
        }
        //append the table data containing the objects property value
        addText(el, "" + item[key]);
      }
    }

    var target = document.getElementById(selector);
    target.innerHTML = "";
    target.appendChild(table);
  }
  //*********************************************
  //******************** INIT *******************
  //*********************************************
  document.getElementById("finalValue").innerHTML = F.toFixed(0);
  document.getElementById("finalValueTwo").innerHTML = calcTable[nper].balance;
  document.getElementById("finalTotalPayments").innerHTML =
    calcTable[nper].totPayment;
  document.getElementById("finalTotalInterest").innerHTML =
    calcTable[nper].totInterest;
  //
  //
  //
  // NEW ARRAY WITH YEARLY PERIODS
  //
  //
  /*
  
  let calcTableShow = [];

  calcTableShow.push({
    period: 0,
    payment: 0,
    totPayment: calcTable[0].totPayment,
    interest: 0,
    totInterest: 0,
    balance: calcTable[0].totPayment
  });

  for (let i = 1; i < nper / 12 + 1; i++) {
    calcTableShow[i] = {
      period: i,
      payment: calcTable[i + i * 12].totPayment,
      totPayment: calcTable[i + i * 12].payment,
      interest: for (let i = 1; i < 13; i++) {calcTable[i].interest},
      totInterest: calcTable[i + i * 12].totInterest,
      balance: calcTable[i + i * 12].balance
    };
  }
  console.log(calcTableShow);
  
  */
  //
  //
  //
}
```

```html
<div class="finalValue">Final Value v.1: <span id="finalValue">0</span></div>
<div class="finalValue">Final Value v.2: <span id="finalValueTwo">0</span></div>
<div class="finalValue">Final Total Payments: <span id="finalTotalPayments">0</span></div>
<div class="finalValue">Final Total Interest: <span id="finalTotalInterest">0</span></div>

<!-- INPUTS -->
<div>
  P: <input id="calc_P" type="number" value="1000">
  <input type="range" value="1000" step="100" max="10000"><br>
</div>
<div>
  A: <input id="calc_A" type="number" value="10">
  <input type="range" value="10" step="10" max="500"><br>
</div>
<div>
  t: <input id="calc_t" type="number" max="50" value="2">
  <input type="range" value="2" max="50"><br>
</div>
<div>
  r: <input id="calc_r" type="number" value="10">
  <input type="range" value="10" step=".1" max="25"><br>
</div>


<!-- TABLE -->
<div id="TblCalc" class="card table-card"></div>


<!-- JS -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="test.js"></script>
```

EDIT:
After the answer provided by Thomas Ludewig, I did not quite understand his logic. I have tried get this to work for several hours but I can not get it right. With the `if (i % 12 == 0)` I am now trying to populate a new array with the yearly results.
I am however bumping into several issues that I am having a hard time figuring out.

Code below:

```js
calculate();

//*********************************************
//************ LINK the INPUTS ****************
//*********************************************

// Select all inputs and add event listener "change" (for calc only).
var inputsArray = document.querySelectorAll("input");
inputsArray.forEach(el => el.addEventListener("change", calculate));

//inputsArray.forEach(el => el.addEventListener("input", linkValue));
//"input"... will cause massive lag with high "t" values...

// Select all inputs and add event listener "input" (for linking values only)
var inputsArrayTwo = document.querySelectorAll("input");
inputsArray.forEach(el => el.addEventListener("input", linkValue));

// Link the range with number inputs
function linkValue(e) {
  var sibling = e.target.previousElementSibling || e.target.nextElementSibling;
  sibling.value = e.target.value;
}

//*********************************************
//************ UPDATE TABLE OBJECT ************
//*********************************************
function calculate() {
  //*********************************************
  //************ VARS and CALCS *****************
  //*********************************************

  let P = parseFloat(document.querySelector("#calc_P").value);  // Starting value
  let r = document.querySelector("#calc_r").value / 100;        // Interest
  let n = 12;                                                   // Compounds per year
  let t = parseFloat(document.querySelector("#calc_t").value);  // Time in years
  let A = parseFloat(document.querySelector("#calc_A").value);  // Deposits per period
  let p = 12;                                                   // Deposit periods yearly (monthly)

  let nper = p * t;                                             // total # periods
  let rate = (1 + r / n) ** (n / p) - 1;                        // interest rate
  let F = P * (1 + rate) ** nper + (A * ((1 + rate) ** nper - 1)) / rate; // Final value
  
//
/* OLD CODE
//
  //  new array
  let calcTable = [];

  //  push first row [0]
  calcTable.push({
    period: 0,
    payment: 0,
    totPayment: P,
    interest: 0,
    totInterest: 0,
    balance: P
  });

  //  add rest of rows, starting at [1]
  for (let i = 1; i < nper + 1; i++) {
    let previous = i - 1;
    let interest = calcTable[previous].balance * rate;
    calcTable[i] = {
      period: i,
      payment: A,
      totPayment: (P += A),
      interest,
      totInterest: interest + calcTable[previous].totInterest,
      balance: calcTable[previous].balance + A + interest
    };
  }
  */
  
//
// NEW CODE
//
  let calcTableNew = [];

calcTableNew.push({
  period: 0,
  payment: 0,
  totPayment: P,
  interest: 0,
  totInterest: 0,
  balance: P
});

for (let i = 1; i < nper / 12 + 1; i++) {
  let calcTableInsideLoop = [];
  for (let i = 1; i < nper + 1; i++) {
    let previous = i - 1;
    let interest = calcTableInsideLoop[previous].balance * rate;
    calcTableInsideLoop[i] = {
      period: i,
      payment: A,
      totPayment: (P += A),
      interest,
      totInterest: interest + calcTableInsideLoop[previous].totInterest,
      balance: calcTableInsideLoop[previous].balance + A + interest
    };
    if (i % 12 == 0) {
      addDataToYearlyArray();
    }
  }
  function addDataToYearlyArray() {
    calcTableNew[i] = {
      period: i,
      payment:
        calcTableInsideLoop[i * 12].totPayment -
        calcTableInsideLoop[i * 12 - 12].totPayment,
      totPayment: calcTableInsideLoop[i * 12].totPayment,
      interest:
        calcTableInsideLoop[i * 12].totInterest -
        calcTableInsideLoop[i * 12 - 12].totInterest,
      totInterest: calcTableInsideLoop[i * 12].totInterest,
      balance: calcTableInsideLoop[i * 12].balance
    };
  }
}

console.log(calcTableNew);
  
  //
  /* THESE FUNCTIONS ARE TEMPORARLY COMMENTED OUT, SHOULD APPLY TO THE NEW ARRAY WITH YEARLY PERIODS
  //
  function setPrecision(table) {
    for (let i = 0; i < table.length; i++) {
      for (let key in table[i]) {
        if (key === "interest" || key === "totInterest" || key === "balance") {
          table[i][key] = table[i][key].toFixed(0);
        }
      }
    }
  }

  setPrecision(calcTable);

  function localeSet(table) {
    for (let i = 0; i < table.length; i++) {
      for (let key in table[i]) {
        if (key === "interest" || key === "totInterest" || key === "balance") {
          table[i][key] = new Intl.NumberFormat("fr", {
            minimumFractionDigits: 0
          }).format(table[i][key]);
        } else {
          table[i][key] = new Intl.NumberFormat("fr").format(table[i][key]);
        }
      }
    }
  }
  localeSet(calcTable);
  */

  //*********************************************
  //************* CREATE HTML TABLE *************
  //*********************************************

  var tableSelector = "TblCalc";

  //call the jsonToTable Function
  jsonToTable(calcTable, tableSelector);

  function addEl(parent, nodeName, className) {
    var element = document.createElement(nodeName);
    if (className) element.className = className;
    if (parent) parent.appendChild(element);
    return element;
  }
  function addText(parent, text) {
    parent.appendChild(document.createTextNode(text));
  }
  function jsonToTable(json, selector) {
    var table = addEl(null, "table", "tbl-container");
    var tbody = addEl(table, "tbody");
    var thr = addEl(tbody, "tr", "tbl-headers");

    //loop through the property names of the first object
    for (var propertyName in json[0]) {
      addText(addEl(thr, "th"), propertyName);
    }

    //loop through the array of objects
    for (var ind = 0; ind < json.length; ind++) {
      var item = json[ind];
      var tr = addEl(tbody, "tr", "tbl-rows");
      //loop though each of the objects properties
      var first = ind != json.length - 1; // no first item for last row
      for (var key in item) {
        var el = addEl(tr, "td");
        if (first) {
          // <---- point of interest
          el = addEl(el, "div", "tbl-name-container ");
          el = addEl(el, "div", "tbl-name-text");
          first = false;
        }
        //append the table data containing the objects property value
        addText(el, "" + item[key]);
      }
    }

    var target = document.getElementById(selector);
    target.innerHTML = "";
    target.appendChild(table);
  }
  //*********************************************
  //******************** INIT *******************
  //*********************************************
  document.getElementById("finalValue").innerHTML = F.toFixed(0);
  document.getElementById("finalValueTwo").innerHTML = calcTable[nper].balance;
  document.getElementById("finalTotalPayments").innerHTML =
    calcTable[nper].totPayment;
  document.getElementById("finalTotalInterest").innerHTML =
    calcTable[nper].totInterest;
}
```

```html
<div class="finalValue">Final Value v.1: <span id="finalValue">0</span></div>
<div class="finalValue">Final Value v.2: <span id="finalValueTwo">0</span></div>
<div class="finalValue">Final Total Payments: <span id="finalTotalPayments">0</span></div>
<div class="finalValue">Final Total Interest: <span id="finalTotalInterest">0</span></div>

<!-- INPUTS -->
<div>
  P: <input id="calc_P" type="number" value="1000">
  <input type="range" value="1000" step="100" max="10000"><br>
</div>
<div>
  A: <input id="calc_A" type="number" value="10">
  <input type="range" value="10" step="10" max="500"><br>
</div>
<div>
  t: <input id="calc_t" type="number" max="50" value="2">
  <input type="range" value="2" max="50"><br>
</div>
<div>
  r: <input id="calc_r" type="number" value="10">
  <input type="range" value="10" step=".1" max="25"><br>
</div>


<!-- TABLE -->
<div id="TblCalc" class="card table-card"></div>


<!-- JS -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="test2.js"></script>
```

I hope someone could help me in the right direction here.
--Frank

EDIT 2 - SOLVED
I found a way to solve my issue with the annual array/table. The code is still a bit messy here and there. But now it is working as intended.

```js
//*********************************************
//************ LINK the INPUTS ****************
//*********************************************

//debugger - delete me
var inputsArrayDebug = document.querySelectorAll("input");
inputsArrayDebug.forEach(el => el.addEventListener("change", debug));

// Select all inputs and add event listener "input" (for linking values only)
var inputsArray = document.querySelectorAll("input");
inputsArray.forEach(el => el.addEventListener("input", linkValue));

// Link the range with number inputs
function linkValue(e) {
  var sibling = e.target.previousElementSibling || e.target.nextElementSibling;
  sibling.value = e.target.value;
  parametersCalculationGet();
  tablesInit(para.P);
  monthlyTableCalculate();
  annualTableCalculate();
}

//*********************************************
//************ CALCULATIONS *******************
//*********************************************

//  set up new empty arrays
var monthlyTable;
var annualTable;
//  create month and annual table array element
//  and push the first row [0]
function tablesInit(P) {
  
  monthlyTable = [];
  annualTable = [];
  var obj = {};
  obj.period = 0;
  obj.payment = 0;
  obj.totPayment = P;
  obj.interest = 0;
  obj.totInterest = 0;
  obj.balance = P;
  monthlyTable.push(obj);
  annualTable.push(obj);
}

function monthlyTableAddNewMonth() {
  var obj = {};
  var previous = monthlyTable.length - 1;
  var interest = monthlyTable[previous].balance * para.rate;
  //  add monthly input datas to month table;
  obj.period = monthlyTable.length;
  obj.payment = para.A;
  obj.totPayment = para.P += para.A;
  obj.interest = interest;
  obj.totInterest = interest + monthlyTable[previous].totInterest;
  obj.balance = monthlyTable[previous].balance + para.A + interest;
  monthlyTable.push(obj);
}

function annualTableAddNewYear() {
  var obj = {};
  var currentAnTable = annualTable.length;
  var previous = monthlyTable.length - 1;
  //  add monthly input datas to month table;
  obj.period = currentAnTable;
  obj.payment =
    monthlyTable[currentAnTable * 12].totPayment -
    monthlyTable[currentAnTable * 12 - 12].totPayment;
  obj.totPayment = monthlyTable[currentAnTable * 12].totPayment;
  obj.interest =
    monthlyTable[currentAnTable * 12].totInterest -
    monthlyTable[currentAnTable * 12 - 12].totInterest;
  obj.totInterest = monthlyTable[currentAnTable * 12].totInterest;
  obj.balance = monthlyTable[currentAnTable * 12].balance;
  annualTable.push(obj);
}

function parametersCalculationGet() {
  //******************************* FIRES VID INPUT
  //  get calculation  parameters and store in object
  para = {};

  para.P = parseFloat(document.querySelector("#calc_P").value); // Starting value
  para.r = document.querySelector("#calc_r").value / 100; // Annual interest
  para.n = 12; // Compounds per year
  para.t = parseFloat(document.querySelector("#calc_t").value); // Time in years
  para.A = parseFloat(document.querySelector("#calc_A").value); // Deposits per period
  para.p = 12; // Deposit periods per year

  para.nper = para.p * para.t; // total number of periods
  para.rate = (1 + para.r / para.n) ** (para.n / para.p) - 1; // calculated interest rate
  para.F =
    para.P * (1 + para.rate) ** para.nper +
    (para.A * ((1 + para.rate) ** para.nper - 1)) / para.rate; // Final value
  return para;
}

//  update monthly payments and interests
function monthlyTableCalculate() {
  // i assume taht hete some parameters for the calculation will be obtained from somewhere
  var para = parametersCalculationGet();

  for (i = 0; i < para.nper; i++) {
    monthlyTableAddNewMonth();
  }
}

function annualTableCalculate() {
  var para = parametersCalculationGet();
  //    if (i % 12 == 0) {   } nice trick but now not needed anymore
  for (i = 0; i < para.t; i++) {
    annualTableAddNewYear();
  }
}



// Init
// Get parameters
parametersCalculationGet();
// Push first row [0] to monthlyTable and annualTable
tablesInit(para.P);
// Calculate and push rest of rows to monthlyTable
monthlyTableCalculate();
annualTableCalculate();

function debug() {
  console.log("monthlyTable");
  console.log(monthlyTable);
  console.log("annualTable");
  console.log(annualTable);
}

console.log("monthlyTable");
console.log(monthlyTable);
console.log("annualTable");
console.log(annualTable);
```

```html
<div class="finalValue">Final Value v.1: <span id="finalValue">0</span></div>
<div class="finalValue">Final Value v.2: <span id="finalValueTwo">0</span></div>
<div class="finalValue">Final Total Payments: <span id="finalTotalPayments">0</span></div>
<div class="finalValue">Final Total Interest: <span id="finalTotalInterest">0</span></div>

<!-- INPUTS -->
<div>
  P: <input id="calc_P" type="number" value="1000">
  <input type="range" value="1000" step="100" max="10000"><br>
</div>
<div>
  A: <input id="calc_A" type="number" value="10">
  <input type="range" value="10" step="10" max="500"><br>
</div>
<div>
  t: <input id="calc_t" type="number" max="50" value="2">
  <input type="range" value="2" max="50"><br>
</div>
<div>
  r: <input id="calc_r" type="number" value="10">
  <input type="range" value="10" step=".1" max="25"><br>
</div>


<!-- TABLE -->
<div id="TblCalc" class="card table-card"></div>


<!-- JS -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="test3.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

*sigh* Ok Ok you are new to js and i wont let you spaghettyfie your first program ...
As you can see, simple things can be done simple :) Please check this formulas - otherwise your boat, your villa and wife will be gone ;)

```
            var monthlyTable ;
            var annualTable  ;
            // set up new empty array
            // vreate new array element
            function monthlyTableInit(P) {
                    monthlyTable=[];
                    var obj = {};
                    obj.period = 0;
                    obj.payment = 0;
                    obj.totPayment = P;
                    obj.interest = 0;
                    obj.totInterest = 0;
                    obj.balance = P;
            };


            function monthlyTableAddNewMonth(payment, totPayment, interest, toInterest, balance) {
                    var obj = {}
                    //  add monthly input datas to month table;
                    obj.period = monthlyTable.lenght;
                    obj.payment = 0;
                    obj.totPayment = P;
                    obj.interest = 0;
                    obj.totInterest = 0;
                    obj.balance = P;
                    monthlyTable.push(obj)
            };

            function parametersCalculationGet() {

                    //get calculation  parameters and store in object
                    para = {};

                    para.P = parseFloat(document.querySelector("#calc_P").value); // Starting value
                    para.r = document.querySelector("#calc_r").value / 100; // Interest
                    para.n = 12; // Compounds per year
                    para.t = parseFloat(document.querySelector("#calc_t").value); // Time in years
                    para.A = parseFloat(document.querySelector("#calc_A").value); // Deposits per period
                    para.p = 12; // Deposit periods yearly (monthly)

                    para.nper = p * t; // total # periods
                    para.rate = (1 + r / n) ** (n / p) - 1; // interest rate
                    para.F = P * (1 + rate) ** nper + (A * ((1 + rate) ** nper - 1)) / rate; // Final value
                    return para
            }
            //update montlys payments and interests

            function monthlyTableCalculate {
                    // i asume taht hete some parameters for the calculation will be obtained from somewhere
                    var para = parametersCalculationGet();

                    for(i = 0; i<monthlyTable.length; i++) {
                            let previous = i - 1;
                            // this matheematics will be buggy i do not know your algorithm
                            var obj = {};
                            obj.period = i;
                            obj.payment = 0;
                            obj.interest = 0;
                            obj.totInterest = 0;
                            obj.totPayment = P;
                            obj.balance = P;
                            obj.interest = calcTableInsideLoop[previous].balance * para.rate;
                            obj.totInterest = interest + calcTableInsideLoop[previous].totInterest;
                            obj.payment = para.A;
                            obj.totPayment = (obj.P += para.A);
                            obj.interest = 0; //  ?
                            obj.totInterest = obj.interest + monthlyTable[previous].totInterest;
                            obj.balance: monthlyTable[previous].balance + obj.A + obj.interest;

                    }
            }

            function anualTableCreate(startMonth) {
                var annualTable =[];
                //    if (i % 12 == 0) {   } nice trick but now not needed anymopre
                    for(i = startMonth; i<monthlyTable.length; i = i + 12) {// ad start as a offset
                            annualTable.push(monthlyTable[i]);
                    }
            }

            function runCalculation() {
                    monthlyTableInit(P);
                    console.log("monthlyTable");
                    console.log(monthlyTable);
                    anualTableCreate(0);
                    console.log("annualTable");
                    console.log(annualTable);
            }
```

Comment: Please use less code (shorthand syntax) where it makes sense.  **Don't:** `obj={}; obj.prop1=val; obj.prop2=val;` -- **Do:** `obj={prop1:val, prop2:val}`.  Also, please notice the lack of "sigh" and condescension ;)

Comment: @ThomasLudewig - I see your point, you are making it simple by dividing the tasks in different functions. My main issue was however how to populate a new array (annualTable) from an already completed array (monthlyTable). I solved it by dividing my code into smaller parts like you did. The key to the algorithm was something I already had thought of, but I did not know how to perform the logic in javascript. I added the working code at the top, "SOLVED". Thank you Thomas for your time and patience with me.

Comment: That looks now much better !  Even you read it in a hurry now its clear what each part is doing :) Some  words on var namings. Single char names should used just for local vars. e.g. for loops. At the moment you write the code you are very clear how genious your abbreations are. Wait 5 years ;) JS is case sensitive. On calculations this can becomes dangerous. They might kill me but in this case i prefer the i_am_always_lowercase_style ;) On my steel calculations it might not be cool if a force becomes zero by a typing mistake :D Have fun and nice coding !